# CodeIgniter routing helping

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can you explain these two lines of code in 
`applications/config/routes.php` file in the CodeIgniter framework?

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following information is taken from the CodeIgniter-Documentation under http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html.

> Routing rules are defined in your application/config/routes.php file. In it you'll see an array called $route that permits you to specify your own routing criteria. Routes can either be specified using wildcards or Regular Expressions

So your first line of code would redirect any call to your domain, when the URI contains no data to the view-Method in the pages-class like that:
`http://example.com/` would redirect to `http://example.com/pages/view/`

The second line would redirect any call to the pages-class/view-method and pass the original URI as parameter like that:

`http://example.com/articles/` would redirect to `http://example.com/pages/view/articles/`

So, basically you're setting up a [Front Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) with these two lines.
Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

In CodeIgniter, each URL can be splitted into class, method and data as stated [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).
Example: `http://example.com/classname/methodname/somedata`.
Normally, calling the URL `http:/example.com/show/1` would call the method `1` in the class `article`. Your second line of code would redirect this call to `http://example.com/pages/view/articles/1` and therefor call the method  `view` in the class `pages` passing the arguments "articles" and "1" as data.

I would like to encourage you to read through the excellent CI-Documentation to fully understand those principles.

Comment: can you please rephrase/elaborate part two(the second line)?

Answer (score -1):

`$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';` //this stands for

when your site is opening which controller function is the default run...

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';//this stands for
```

in pages controller view function parameter id default 1

for more info refer this i think this might help you...:-)
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html